# How to determine if the differential is homogeneous or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need help determining whether the following operators are linear homogeneous, linear inhomogeneous or non-linear and how can we know. This is is actually from my own knowledge, and I want to determine the main key points to look out for when determining those characterstic.

I know that in order for it to be a linear operator $L(u+v)=L(u) + L(v)$ and $L(cu) = cL(u)$
Do I have to try finding these to determine if its linear or not?

For example I have four equations, it tells me to solve them but first to figure out if they are linear homogeneous, linear inhomogeneous or non-linear.

$$\tag{1} \ L(u) = u - u_y + u_{xx} + e^xy$$

$$\tag{2} \ L(u) = u^2 - u_xu_y$$

$$\tag{3} \ L(u) = u_x + y^2u_y$$

$$\tag{4} \ L(u) = u - u_{xxx} + u_y + \cos(u)$$

So from what I learned so far I know that if the differential equation is equal to $0$ it is linear. For example, I believe the first and third problems are linear homogenous and the second is linear inhomogenous (because of $u_xu_y$) and the fourth problem is non linear because of $\cos(u)$

any help or hints would be helpful.

Thank you

Comment: I think you might be confusing "equations" for "operators". You're asking about solving equations, but I see no equations to solve, so I assume it's $L(u) = 0$. If $L$ satisfies the two properties you mentioned above, $L$ is a linear operator, and an equation of the form $L(u) = 0$ is said to be linear and homogeneous. When $L$ is not a linear operator, there may be a possibility to rewrite $L(u) = 0$ as $K(u) = f(x, y)$ where $K$ is a linear operator. If this is possible, the differential equation is commonly called linear non-homogeneous. Otherwise, it's non-linear.

Comment: Its just saying determine if they are linear homogeneous, inhomogeneous or non linear

Comment: So I guess it is the equation $L(u) = 0$. What I said seems to apply. (1) would be linear inhomogeneous, (2) would be non-linear, (3) would be linear homogeneous, and (4) would be non-linear.

Comment: could you explain how you got that. Like I only understand number 2 and why its non linear, because we have a u^2. I am pretty is sure (1) right because of e^(xy) but i dont understand 3 and 4

Comment: and i think 4 would be linear non homogenous>?

Comment: 4 is not linear because it has $\cos(u)$.